# Why am I Getting Duplicate Notifications?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use Firebase functions to automatically send push notifications to iOS devices. More specifically, right now when a user creates a post, it will contain an ID, which is actually the user's FCM token, from which the push notification will be sent to that user.

Why does it happen that, upon creating a post, my iOS device doesn't necessarily receive a single push notification, but many? Why is the getResult function being triggered potentially more than once for a given post?

Please see my code below. Thanks!

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var firebase = require('firebase');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var config = {
  apiKey: "XXXXX",
  authDomain: "YYYYY",
  databaseURL: "ZZZZZ"
}

firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.database().ref('posts').on('child_added', function(snapshot1) {
   snapshot1.forEach((child) => {
    if (child.key == 'id') {
      var token = child.val();
      admin.database().ref('users').on('value', function(snapshot2) {
        snapshot2.forEach(function(user) {
          if (user.val().fcmToken == token) {
            var newBadgeCount = user.val().badge + 1;
            const payload = {
              notification: {
               title: 'Hello, World!',
               body: 'Test Message!',
               badge: '' + newBadgeCount,
               sound: 'default'
              }
            };
            function getResult(token) {
              return result = admin.database().ref('fcmToken/' + token).once('value').then(allToken => {
                if (allToken.val()) {
                  const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
                  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(function (response) {
                    console.log("Successfully sent message: ", response.results[0].error);
                  }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
                  });
                };
              });
            }
            function updateBadgeCount(badgeCount, userID) {
              firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID + '/badge').set(badgeCount);
            }
            Promise.all([getResult(token)]).then(function(snapshots) {
              updateBadgeCount(newBadgeCount, user.key);
            });
          };
        });
      }, function (errorObject) {
           console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
      });
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase triggers for each record of all records with `'child_added'` option once and will re-trigger after each new child added. So, If you like to trigger a function on new write options, you need use other ways.

```
exports.sendNotifycation = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postId}')
     .onWrite(event => {

      Your new re-designed codes. (in case I will complete remain)


})
```